# How to connect a MySQL database to C++ on Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, mysql, ubuntu

I am trying to make a database management system in C++, however I have been struggling for many hours to even connect the MySQL to my program.

I am fairy new to C++, but I have experience in Java, and it was never such a pain connecting to MySQL.

I have tried over a dozen variations of the code below, yet I still have not succeeded.

How do I go about connecting a MySQL database to C++ for Linux?

**My code at the moment looks like this:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <mysql_driver.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;
    sql::ConnectOptionsMap connection_properties;

    /* Create a connection */
    driver = sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver::get_mysql_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "rootpass");

    /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
    con->setSchema("test");

    delete con;
    return 0;
}
```

**And these are the errors I receive:**

error: ‘get_mysql_driver_instance’ is not a member of ‘sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver’
     driver = sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver::get_mysql_driver_instance();

CMakeFiles/SuperStorage.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/SuperStorage.dir/main.cpp.o' failed
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/SuperStorage.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/SuperStorage.dir/all' failed
make[2]:**  [CMakeFiles/SuperStorage.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/SuperStorage.dir/rule' failed
make[1]:  **[CMakeFiles/SuperStorage.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'SuperStorage' failed
make: *** [SuperStorage] Error 2

Comment: 1) post a [mcve]. 2) include the proper header files. 3) link the appropriate libraries. 4) what IDE you use has *nothing* to do with it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl 1) I have tried many alternatives that have not worked for me, but I'll update it with the code I currently have. I'll also include the header files and libraries. 4) Yeah I know, but all the tutorials and examples I found show it working with Visual C++ and I haven't been able to succeed with those methods because they seem to be Visual C++ specific.

Comment: I can't quite understand how the solution (see answer below) wasn't one of the "over a dozen" variations that you allegedly tried. Please do not blame your not-reading on C++ and make it into a "Java is better" language war.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I applied your solution which removed the error regarding "MySQL_Driver", however the other errors still remain. And your version was one of the many solutions I looked at (including dev.mysql.com). I make sure to do my work before asking for help. And I am not having a language war at all, if I thought C++ was inferior to Java, then I wouldn't even bother learning it. All languages have their specific uses. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: What "other errors"? The only other errors you showed us were the Make level telling us that the C++ compilation failed. There were no other C++ compilation errors, so there is nothing left for Make to reject. You are omitting something.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit As I've mentioned, I am fairly new to C++ and I take it by your response that the message in Make means that there is an issue with the connection?

Comment: No, the message in Make has nothing to do with the connection. Where did you get that from? As I said in my previous comment, the message in Make tells you that the C++ compilation failed (which you knew already). There is no reason for the message in Make to still be there given that you have fixed the C++ compilation error. Therefore, there is something you are not showing us. What "other errors" are you concerned about?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The code is exactly what I posted on here, but update with your fix. But I still receive the same message in Make. The "other errors" I refer to is the message in Make.

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I appreciate the help you are giving me, so I wouldn't lie or leave out any information. But that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

> ```
> driver = sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver::get_mysql_driver_instance();
> ```

It should be:

```
driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
```

This is [clearly shown in the old MySQL C++ Connector tutorial page for connecting to a database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-connecting.html) (though the 8.0 documentation seems to have removed all usage examples ).